# D3 selection html -- index starting at 1 instead of 0 when passing function

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm confused about this behavior and was hoping someone might have some insight. I have an array defined as:

```
arr_subpop_unique = ["CPL", "NAP", "NPL", "SAP", "SPL", "TPL", "UMW", "WMT", "XER"]
```

My D3 script is such:

```
var sizemapHeader = d3.select("#d3-sizemap-hr").selectAll("div")
        .data(arr_subpop_unique)
      .enter().append("div")
        .attr("class", "sizemap-hr-title ellipsis scroll_on_hover")
        .html(function(d,i){ console.log(d,i); return d; });
```

The issue is that the index is starting on 1, so I am losing the "CPL" value. I'm logging this in the console and it clearly starts at 1 instead of 0.  Can anyone see a problem with this?

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried your code and I get the CPL, all I did was change #d3-sizemap-hr to body. Is it possible you have some CSS related to that d3-sizemap-hr that is hiding/blocking it?

Comment: Do you already have a `<div>` inside `#d3-sizemap-hr` by any chance?

Comment: @GregL -  Awesome. Yes, I had a spacer <div>.  Removed it and it works great.  Want to add this as an answer and I'll accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you already have a `<div>` inside the element with an ID of `d3-sizemap-hr`.

The reason this is a problem is that you are only populating elements in the `.enter()` state, which will not occur for the existing div.

I have the following recommendations:

- Always have a unique class for your dynamically added elements with D3
- Have the minimum possible for the `.enter()` state, such as your `.append()` and then any other static styles that don't ever vary based on the data changing. Everything else goes in the update state.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations as well.  I'm able to get some things built in D3, but I'm still not fully grasping the fundamentals of the enter/update/exit. Getting there one step at a time.  Thanks again!

Comment: I found [this page](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) by Mike Bostock himself helpful with getting my head around that stuff.

Comment: I know what you mean, thefreeline.  I found [this page](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection) helpful.  Reading one good explanation once isn't enough for me.  It takes practice.