# d3.each() index doesn't begin at 0

Tags: javascript, d3.js, foreach, each

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29337471/d3-selection-html-index-starting-at-1-instead-of-0-when-passing-function). The solution there was that there was a `<div>` messing things up. There are no `<divs>` in mine.

I have this CoffeeScript code:

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
d3.select("body")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .each((d, i) =>
    console.log(i, d)
  )
```

With the **desired** console output being:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

The **actual** console output is:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
```

I can get the desired output with this code:

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
d3.select("body")
  .data(data)
  .each((d, i) =>
    console.log(i, d)
  ).enter()
   .each((d, i) =>
    console.log(i, d)
  )
```

But it just feels wrong to have two .each() calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d3.each()` **does** begin at index `0`. What you're seeing in your code is the expected behaviour, given what you have in your code.

The issue here is simple: there is a `<body>` element in the page, of course. Your data array has 5 elements, and one of them is being bound to the `<body>`.

Let's show this. Have a look at the size of the "enter" selection:

```js
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
var foo = d3.select("body")
  .data(data)
  .enter();

console.log("Size of enter selection: " + foo.size())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

We can also show that the first element in the array was bound to the `<body>`:

```js
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
var foo = d3.select("body")
  .data(data)
  .enter();

console.log("Data of body: " + d3.select("body").data())
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Yet another way for showing this is using the third argument (technically speaking, parameter), which is the current group:

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
d3.select("body")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .each((d, i, p) =>
  //           ^---- this is the third argument
    console.log(p)
  )
```

Here I cannot provide a working Stack snippet, because it crashes if we try to log a D3 selection. But the result will be this:

```
[undefined × 1, EnterNode, EnterNode, EnterNode, EnterNode]
```

That `undefined` is the "update" selection (the body), and the 4 `EnterNode`s are the "enter" selection. And that brings us to the explanation of why `each()` behaves that way in your code.

If you have a look at the source code...

```
function(callback) {

    for (var groups = this._groups, j = 0, m = groups.length; j < m; ++j) {
        for (var group = groups[j], i = 0, n = group.length, node; i < n; ++i) {
            if (node = group[i]) callback.call(node, node.__data__, i, group);
        }
    }

    return this;
}
```

You're gonna see that it works comparing the nodes to the group, and your group contains both the "update" selection and the "enter" selection. The update selection corresponds to index `0` and the enter selection corresponds to indices `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.

---

**Solution**:

This is what you want, pay attention to `selectAll` and `null`:

```js
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
d3.select("body")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .each((d, i) =>
    console.log(i, d)
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
```

Thus, as you can see, selecting `null` assure us that our "enter" selection  always have all the elements in the data array.

---

**Bonus**: `select` and `selectAll` behave differently. Most people think that the only difference is that the former selects only 1 element and the latter selects all the elements. But there are more subtle differences. Have a look at this table:

| Method | select() | selectAll() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Selection | selects the first element that matches the selector string | selects all elements that match the selector string |
| Grouping | Does not affect grouping | Affects grouping |
| Data propagation | Propagates data | Doesn't propagate data |

Comment: +1 nice and complete! I didn't know about `select(null)`. Does that mean that the `body` won't have the data attached to it? Are there any caveats that you are aware of when using `select(null)`?

Comment: No. `select(null)` and `selectAll(null)` are the safer and, the most important, the faster way to make sure that the data method compares the data with an empty selection.

Comment: Very informative. I appreciate your time, and that the solution worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31234678/d3-function-only-iterating-though-last-point-of-data-in-an-array)
and basically this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19726610/3433323

Quoting: 
`You need to select the non-existent elements as well for the selections to work properly. ... At the moment, the selection you're matching data against contains only the one element`
Which means you are selecting against the body only.

In short:

```
data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
d3.selectAll("body")
  .selectAll('div') // add this
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .each((d, i) =>
    console.log(i, d)
  )
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oLb3j76g/)

[About selectAll](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5369146)

Comment: That's interesting. I see that it is working in jsfiddle, yet it doesn't work in my case. Thank you though :)